# Entity Framework Multi-Tenant (Single database Multiple Schema) With Code First Migration

Tags: entity-framework

We have created Entity Framework Multi-Tenant (Single database Multiple Schema) With Code First like in this example http://romiller.com/2011/05/23/ef-4-1-multi-tenant-with-code-first/. Our database is live. Now we are facing very serious problem. We need some changes in our entity. The question is that how we update our database for each schema table. Is there possible Migration in current scenario?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? We are developing a multitenant application and need to decide whether to use multiple schemas or single one.

Comment: Yes we find the solution. And We noticed that there is no effect if we change the structure of the entity in model in our application

Comment: See [Multi-Tenant With Code First EF6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458943/multi-tenant-with-code-first-ef6)