# Multi-Tenant With Code First EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Our organization has need to have a single database, multi-tenant
(**by table schema, not by  tenant id**) architecture.

There is a great article here on getting started with this kind of thing here: 
http://romiller.com/2011/05/23/ef-4-1-multi-tenant-with-code-first/

In the middle of the article, this is written:

> You’ll notice (probably with some dismay) we need to write code to
>   configure the table schema for each entity. Admittedly there aren’t
>   many magic unicorns grazing around this code… in future versions of EF
>   we will be able to replace this with a much cleaner custom convention.

Our goal is to have the cleanest way possible of having a single context class that we can use to connect to multiple schemas that have the same model.
(**Note that modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema doesn't seem sufficient**, because it only applies that the first time EF initializes the context and runs OnModelCreating)

Does the aforementioned cleaner custom convention exist in EF5 or EF6?
Or is there a cleaner way to handle this somehow?

Note: I also asked this question on the development forum, as it seems to relate more to the direction of EF, but wanted to see if anybody here had alternatives.

Note2: I'm not worried about migrations, we'll handle that seperately.

Comment: Just curious - how many tenants?  how many simultaneous users?

Comment: Tenants could be in the 100s. simultaneous users would be low, maybe 100 at most is my guess.

Comment: why not you handle it at database design level? for instance a column in every table with the tenant Id in it and handle it at the repository level.

Comment: @AsifMushtaq, my assumption is because of security.

Comment: @AsifMushtaq Gabrielius is right, there are different approaches for different security needs. It's easier to make a mistake with the tenantId approach frankly (Though another project I work on uses that exact approach). Here are some details on the pros/cons of different tenancy approaches: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx#mlttntda_topic2

Comment: I agree mistakes can be made with this approach but its seems to be simpler approach.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The property `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema` in `OnModelCreating` is sufficient **if** you implement `IDbModelCacheKeyProvider` on your `DbContext`. A model is created once and than cached internally by `EntityFramwork` and you can define your own key for the cache. Take the schema name as model cache key and EF will create a model by every different cache key (schema in our case). Here is my proof of concept code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using TenantDataModel;

namespace TenantDataContext
{
    public class TenantDataCtx : DbContext, IDbModelCacheKeyProvider
    {
        #region Construction

        public static TenantDataCtx Create(string databaseServer, string databaseName, string databaseUserName, string databasePassword, Guid tenantId)
        {
            var connectionStringBuilder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = databaseServer;
            connectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
            connectionStringBuilder.UserID = databaseUserName;
            connectionStringBuilder.Password = databasePassword;

            string connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
            return new TenantDataCtx(connectionString, tenantId);
        }

        // Used by EF migrations
        public TenantDataCtx()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<TenantDataCtx>(null);
        }

        internal TenantDataCtx(string connectionString, Guid tenantId)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<TenantDataCtx>(null);
            this.SchemaName = tenantId.ToString("D");
        }

        public string SchemaName { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        #region DataSet Properties

        public DbSet<TestEntity> TestEntities { get { return this.Set<TestEntity>(); } }

        #endregion

        #region Overrides

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            if (this.SchemaName != null)
            {
                modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(this.SchemaName);
            }

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDbModelCacheKeyProvider Members

        public string CacheKey
        {
            get { return this.SchemaName; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Furthermore I have found a way to use EF migrations. I am not really happy with my solution but it seems that there are no other solutions available right now.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TenantDatabaseManager
{
    public class SqlServerSchemaAwareMigrationSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
    {
        private string _schema;

        public SqlServerSchemaAwareMigrationSqlGenerator(string schema)
        {
            _schema = schema;
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.AddColumnOperation addColumnOperation)
        {
            string newTableName = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(addColumnOperation.Table);
            var newAddColumnOperation = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.AddColumnOperation(newTableName, addColumnOperation.Column, addColumnOperation.AnonymousArguments);
            base.Generate(newAddColumnOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.AddPrimaryKeyOperation addPrimaryKeyOperation)
        {
            addPrimaryKeyOperation.Table = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(addPrimaryKeyOperation.Table);
            base.Generate(addPrimaryKeyOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.AlterColumnOperation alterColumnOperation)
        {
            string tableName = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(alterColumnOperation.Table);
            var newAlterColumnOperation = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.AlterColumnOperation(tableName, alterColumnOperation.Column, alterColumnOperation.IsDestructiveChange);
            base.Generate(newAlterColumnOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.DropPrimaryKeyOperation dropPrimaryKeyOperation)
        {
            dropPrimaryKeyOperation.Table = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(dropPrimaryKeyOperation.Table);
            base.Generate(dropPrimaryKeyOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.CreateIndexOperation createIndexOperation)
        {
            string name = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(createIndexOperation.Table);
            createIndexOperation.Table = name;
            base.Generate(createIndexOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
        {
            string newTableName = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(createTableOperation.Name);
            var newCreateTableOperation = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.CreateTableOperation(newTableName, createTableOperation.AnonymousArguments);
            newCreateTableOperation.PrimaryKey = createTableOperation.PrimaryKey;
            foreach (var column in createTableOperation.Columns)
            {
                newCreateTableOperation.Columns.Add(column);
            }

            base.Generate(newCreateTableOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.RenameTableOperation renameTableOperation)
        {
            string oldName = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(renameTableOperation.Name);
            string newName = renameTableOperation.NewName.Split(new char[] { '.' }).Last();
            var newRenameTableOperation = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.RenameTableOperation(oldName, newName, renameTableOperation.AnonymousArguments);
            base.Generate(newRenameTableOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.RenameIndexOperation renameIndexOperation)
        {
            string tableName = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(renameIndexOperation.Table);
            var newRenameIndexOperation = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.RenameIndexOperation(tableName, renameIndexOperation.Name, renameIndexOperation.NewName);
            base.Generate(newRenameIndexOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.AddForeignKeyOperation addForeignKeyOperation)
        {
            addForeignKeyOperation.DependentTable = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(addForeignKeyOperation.DependentTable);
            addForeignKeyOperation.PrincipalTable = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(addForeignKeyOperation.PrincipalTable);
            base.Generate(addForeignKeyOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.DropColumnOperation dropColumnOperation)
        {
            string newTableName = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(dropColumnOperation.Table);
            var newDropColumnOperation = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.DropColumnOperation(newTableName, dropColumnOperation.Name, dropColumnOperation.AnonymousArguments);
            base.Generate(newDropColumnOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.RenameColumnOperation renameColumnOperation)
        {
            string newTableName = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(renameColumnOperation.Table);
            var newRenameColumnOperation = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.RenameColumnOperation(newTableName, renameColumnOperation.Name, renameColumnOperation.NewName);
            base.Generate(newRenameColumnOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.DropTableOperation dropTableOperation)
        {
            string newTableName = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(dropTableOperation.Name);
            var newDropTableOperation = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.DropTableOperation(newTableName, dropTableOperation.AnonymousArguments);
            base.Generate(newDropTableOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.DropForeignKeyOperation dropForeignKeyOperation)
        {
            dropForeignKeyOperation.PrincipalTable = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(dropForeignKeyOperation.PrincipalTable);
            dropForeignKeyOperation.DependentTable = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(dropForeignKeyOperation.DependentTable);
            base.Generate(dropForeignKeyOperation);
        }

        protected override void Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.DropIndexOperation dropIndexOperation)
        {
            dropIndexOperation.Table = _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(dropIndexOperation.Table);
            base.Generate(dropIndexOperation);
        }

        private string _GetNameWithReplacedSchema(string name)
        {
            string[] nameParts = name.Split('.');
            string newName;

            switch (nameParts.Length)
            {
                case 1:
                    newName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", _schema, nameParts[0]);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    newName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", _schema, nameParts[1]);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    newName = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", _schema, nameParts[1], nameParts[2]);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            return newName;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I use the `SqlServerSchemaAwareMigrationSqlGenerator`:

```
// Update TenantDataCtx
var tenantDataMigrationsConfiguration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration<TenantDataContext.TenantDataCtx>();
tenantDataMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
tenantDataMigrationsConfiguration.SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new SqlServerSchemaAwareMigrationSqlGenerator(schemaName));
tenantDataMigrationsConfiguration.SetHistoryContextFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", (existingConnection, defaultSchema) => new HistoryContext(existingConnection, schemaName));
tenantDataMigrationsConfiguration.TargetDatabase = new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbConnectionInfo(connectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");
tenantDataMigrationsConfiguration.MigrationsAssembly = typeof(TenantDataContext.TenantDataCtx).Assembly;
tenantDataMigrationsConfiguration.MigrationsNamespace = "TenantDataContext.Migrations.TenantData";

DbMigrator tenantDataCtxMigrator = new DbMigrator(tenantDataMigrationsConfiguration);
tenantDataCtxMigrator.Update();
```

Regards from Germany,

Tobias

Comment: Hi Tobias. Where do you call the code stated in 'And this is how I use the SqlServerSchemaAwareMigrationSqlGenerator'? Do you plug this in Configuration? Or do you run this elsewhere? Regards from The Netherlands, Peter.

Comment: Hi Peter. This code applies all migrations existing in 'tenantDataMigrationsConfiguration.MigrationsAssembly' to a database identified by 'tenantDataMigrationsConfiguration.TargetDatabase'. You can execute that code wherever you want to. I have a tiny console application which gets all required parameters via command line arguments, builds a connection string with it and executes the code.

Comment: One important advice: SqlServerSchemaAwareMigrationSqlGenerator is absolutely not complete! Some days ago I had to overwrote the overload for 'Generate(RenameTableOperation renameTableOperation)' for example. To get completeness you have to overwrite all 'Generate' overloads which has something to do with a schema.

Comment: @Tobias Can you post your updated version here? We have problems to get the table renaming workig. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @ManuelAmstutz. Just added the following Generate overrides: AddPrimaryKeyOperation, AlterColumnOperation, DropPrimaryKeyOperation, RenameTableOperation, RenameIndexOperation, RenameColumnOperation, DropForeignKeyOperation, DropIndexOperation. This is all we have right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot - Dankeschön

Comment: @Tobias Hi, I use your solution with few changes. It works nice, thanks, but I found next issue - when I use CacheKey it creates model for each schema and each such model takes around 2Mb. As are result when I have 500 tenants it takes around 1Gb memory, so it is a big issue in case of 1000 and more tenants. Do you have similar issue with memory?

Comment: @Anatoliy Hey. Good point! I think you are right. Memory could became a problem. Mabye you can unload cached models after some time? I don't know if the EF api supports that. Or maybe EF has some build-in meachanism and does that automatically for you?! We do not have the problem because since Microsoft introduced Azure SQL Elastic Database Pools we have switched to one-database-per-tenant.

Comment: Great, clean implementation!

Answer (score 2):

Well, if it would not be code first, I will try to do it this way:

- generate tables in default schema, say dbo
- generate edmx based on existing database
- take EF with POCO as starting TT template
- edit TT file and add new property to context called `schema` and will force the queries in generated classes to use it for database objects.

This way you will be able to create contexts for different schemas and even allow objects to fly around between contexts.

Comment: That's interesting thanks! But my goal (above) is to do this with a single context so I can share the model easily, and reconnect as needed to different schemas within a single app run. Besides that, I might have 50 or 100 different schemas (ALL with the same model), so I wouldn't want to generate a new context every time I want to provision a new tenant (schema). - Your solution would work really well though if I only had a few schemas though!

Comment: @KevinRadcliffe well, you will recreate contexts quite often anyway as in most cases they implement Unit Of Work pattern and not supposed to live prolonged amount of time.

Comment: @KevinRadcliffe And about schema - I would really do it separately, like calling create schema script, since you managing migrations separately anyway.

Answer (score 2):

very nice approach and it helped me to get a more straight forward solution.
You may override only the Name-Method, it is used in every writer ....
Sorry for new answer, but i'm not allowed to comment ....

```
public class SqlServerSchemaAwareMigrationSqlGenerator:SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{

    private string _schema;

    public accountMigrationSqlGenerator(string schema)
    {
        _schema = schema;
    }

    protected override string Name(string name)
    {

        int p = name.IndexOf('.');
        if(p>0)
        {
            name = name.Substring(p + 1);
        }

        return $"[{_schema}].[{name}]";

    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not all functions use Name property, for example Generate for RenameIndexOperation ignores it. So it is more safely to override all Generate methods.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to: [Tobias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1536921/tobias-j)! You save me a years...

My modification for Oracle DB under EF 6:

```
public class IntegrationDbContext : DbContext, IDbModelCacheKeyProvider
{
    private static readonly ILog __log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    /// <summary>
    /// Factory method
    /// </summary>
    public static IntegrationDbContext Create(string connectionStringName)
    {
        return new IntegrationDbContext(connectionStringName, GetDBSchema(connectionStringName));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public IntegrationDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<IntegrationDbContext>(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    internal IntegrationDbContext(string connectionString, string schemaName)
        : base("name={0}".Fill(connectionString))
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<IntegrationDbContext>(null);
        SchemaName = schemaName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DB schema name
    /// </summary>
    public string SchemaName { get; private set; }

    #region Tables
    /// <summary>
    /// Integration table "SYNC_BONUS_DISTRIBUTION"
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DbSet<SYNC_BONUS_DISTRIBUTION> SYNC_BONUS_DISTRIBUTION { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Integration table "SYNC_MESSAGE_DISTRIBUTION"
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DbSet<SYNC_MESSAGE_DISTRIBUTION> SYNC_MESSAGE_DISTRIBUTION { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Integration table "IMPORT_TEMPLATES"
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DbSet<IMPORT_TEMPLATE> IMPORT_TEMPLATES { get; set; }

    #endregion //Tables

    private static Dictionary<string, string> __schemaCache = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private static object __schCacheLock = new object();
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets DB schema name from connection string, or default from config
    /// </summary>
    private static string GetDBSchema(string connectionStringName)
    {
        string result;
        if (!__schemaCache.TryGetValue(connectionStringName, out result))
        {
            lock (__schCacheLock)
            {
                if (!__schemaCache.TryGetValue(connectionStringName, out result))
                {
                    DbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
                    builder.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;
                    result = builder.ContainsKey("User ID") ? builder["User ID"] as string : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultIntegrationSchema"];
                    __schemaCache.Add(connectionStringName, result);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Context initialization
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        __log.DebugFormat("OnModelCreating for integration model in schema: {0}", SchemaName);
        if (SchemaName != null)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(SchemaName);
        }
        //### CLOB settings
        modelBuilder.Properties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) &&
                                             p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MaxLengthAttribute), false).Length == 0)
                                                .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(2000));

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implementation of <see cref="IDbModelCacheKeyProvider.CacheKey"/> - thanks by this is 'OnModelCreating' calling for each specific schema.
    /// </summary>
    public string CacheKey
    {
        get { return SchemaName; }
    }
}
```